# Put table parameters as macro newcommand

Tags: macros, tabularx

i want to use commands to avoid defining tables parameters each time.

```
\begin{listliketab}


\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\bfseries}l @{\hspace{.5em}} XR}
    2009--present & very long text 1, very long text 2, very long text 3, very long text 4, very long text 5, very long text 6, very long text 7, very long text 8, very long text 9, very long text 10 \\
    2009          & Masters                                                                                                                                                                              \\
    2006          & Bachelors
  \end{tabularx}
\end{listliketab}
```

parameters: `{\linewidth}{@{}>{\bfseries}l @{\hspace{.5em}} XR}`

Comment: Please make our life easier by providing a complete working document (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`), not just a fragment.

Comment: why don't you use a list (which is almost always better than tabularx for this kind of layout)

Comment: just use `\newenviornment{foo}{\tabularx{\linewidth}{@{}>{\bfseries}l @{\hspace{.5em}} XR}}{\endtabularx}`

Answer (score 1):

You can define new environments such as

```
\newenvironment{foo}{%
  \tabularx{\linewidth}{@{}>{\bfseries}l @{\hspace{.5em}} XR}}{%
  \endtabularx}
```

and then your tables just need

```
\begin{foo}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{foo}
```